# How to push code using Github API?

Tags: node.js, git, github, git-push

I want to push a directory to Github via nodejs app. Here's what I currently do. 
I take username, password and new repository name from user. Then, I create new repository via Github API(https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create).
Now I want to push some specific code to this repository. I can't use node.js child process (git push origin master), because that requires username and password.
How can I push code to Github via API. (And if via command line, then without entering password manually)

Comment: can you please elaborate the complete process?

Comment: If you use a ssh key, you can use the command line without enter password.

Answer (score 1):

To skip the password on each commit you need to tell the git to store the credential in a separate place. This can be done by using the following command:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

This will store the password [for 15 minutes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/git-credential-cache.html#_examples). If you wish you can extend this time by specifying the amount of duration in milliseconds:

```
git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=3600"
```

Comment: Maybe it's better if you elaborate

Comment: I have node-angular app, and i ask user his github username and password via UI. Now at the backend, i want to push some code to user's github account.